# Accepted a job offer but is it too late to consider a counter-offer?

Tags: job-offer, new-job, job-change, counter-offer

I have been struggling with a decision between two new job offers that I received on the same day.

Option A is a comms agency working for a client that I wanted to work in the future. (Star client lets call it)

Option B is a brand that belongs to the same industry as the star client but their business is in a smaller scale.

Option A is offering a position as regional account manager (I have 6+ years experience in comms) and option B is for marketing senior (I have 2 years experience) both payments are the same and both of them seems to be really interested in me.

With option A I'm considering that working with them for the Star Client can get me closer to do networking with them and hopefully the Star Client can offer me a job someday.

However, being an agency I will also share my time with another client that is not my cup of tea precisely. Talked with the CEO of the agency and he told me that my profile was considered for both clients and he gave me a call to ease up my mind regarding this and even he mentioned that he would like me to meet the rest of the agency team in another country so I will be traveling soon. He also offered a bonus if I accept the offer before the week ended.

With option B is that they offer a marketing position in which I consider to gather experience in the industry directly and apply for a position with the Star Client someday.

After days thinking pros and cons, I accepted Option A proposal and will be signing my contract in two days. I havent seen the contract yet and I believe it was not correct asking them if there was a clause about employees cannot work for Star Client should I leave the company though.

When I gave notice about not accepting the offer of Option B, they arranged a call with me to negotiate and even asking how they can match up the offer and career path Option A is offering me. One thing they confirmed is that they cannot offer any regional role as it's not a priority for the business.

At this point its convenient to accept Option B counter offer or advise option A about it so they can offer a better contract? Or is it too late to consider Option B?

Does backing up for any of these options will burn bridges with any of them?

Hope I wasn't so confusing explaining.

---

Thank you for your answers. An additional question is that if I stick with Option A, could I mention them that Im being counter offered by Option B so I can get  better proposal? Or is too late?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere but nothing's been signed. A company can also go back on their word before actually sealing a deal, they can terminate an employee without warning so someone can't changed their mind before signing the contract?

Comment: Of course once you have changed your mind there is no going back to option A, at least not in the short term.

Comment: A persons word is his their bond. The rest is paper work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience stick with your first choice.

You made that choice for the right reasons at the time; some were objective, others instinctive.

When you go through a tough time – which all jobs have – you'll think that the original job would have been better.

Go with your gut feeling.

Comment: *"You picked up your auctioneer's hammer and brought it down."*  With that, "the deal was struck." You made a promise to employer #1, and now they are beginning the process of relying on it "in good faith."  Now, assuming that they really do fulfill their part of their bargain to you, you should honor your promise, likewise "in good faith."